# Changing Control Panel theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

There are numerous pages online that I have found that describe what I need to do. I need to change the `portal_ext.properties` file with the theme:

```
control.panel.layout.regular.theme.id=mytheme_WAR_mythemetheme
```

I've changed the property in my `portal-ext.properties` file and I've even added a copy of the file to my portlet structure (`docroot/WEB-INF`). I've deployed, restarted tomcat, etc. No changes at all.

What am I missing? Better question - Why is this so unnecessarily difficult?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could do this from control panel.

1. Log in as Admin (`test@lifery.com` unless changed)
2. Make sure you have deployed your theme.
3. Go to: Control Panel → Portal Settings → Display Settings → Look and Feel → Default Control Panel Theme, and select your theme from the drop-down options.

Comment: Thank you - I spent 40 minutes looking for this. I was convinced it existed!

Comment: Maybe you've even been through that previously and submitted the underlying form. This would store the same values in the database. And when there's a conflict between what's in portal-ext.properties and what's in the database - guess who wins: the database.

Answer (score 0):

Correct name of the file is portal-ext.properties not portal_ext.properties.

This file should go under your LIFERAY_HOME folder where LIFERAY_HOME is where liferay is deployed. Just create or edit this file at this location with this property and restart the server

Comment: Sorry - I put underscore instead of dash. I'll try your suggestion.